# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportedElement" when adding a new Always Encrypted column to an existing table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, always-encrypted

Using Visual Studio database projects (SSDT) I added a new column to an existing table. I am using Always Encrypted to encrypt individual columns. When I add the column and try to publish, I get a popup in Visual Studio that says "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportedElement".

If I don't encrypt the column, it works.
If I clear the existing data out of the table, it works.
But just trying to add a new nullable encrypted column does not publish. It will not even generate the script that would be applied.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

I ran the daxFX and SSDT logging and viewed the logs with Windows Event Viewer, but I just see the same error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportedElement".

This is what the added column definition looks like.

```
[MyNewColumn] INT ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [DefaultColumnEncryptionKey], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
```

I expect Visual Studio to publish successfully, adding my new nullable encrypted column but the actual behavior is a pop up that states "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportedElement".

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue, except I had decrypted the column to perform a lookup based on it that I couldn't while it was encrypted (this is a local development db).

The solution was to just perform the encryption manually via SSMS and then run the publish. I'm not sure why VS can't publish the changes, the encryption keys are stored in the local cert store and VS is running as admin but it might not be able to access the keys to encrypt the data but SSMS can.

Comment: Did your process use any CI/CD?  I'm currently trying to solve this as a matter of making development around encryption seemless

Comment: @CaptainPrinny we do, though we don't have a seamless process with always encrypted and we don't let our CI/CD process encrypt/decrypt data. The CI/CD "server" needs access to the encryption keys and we've been hesitant to do. For now encryption of a new column/table is fine because it is empty and you can deploy the changes easily, but existing data being encrypted or decrypted is being done manually.